# Using Knitro or Xpress SLP via FICO Xpress Python API for Local and Global Solve Methods

Tags: nonlinear-programming, nonconvex-programming

Can someone guide me on how to utilize the FICO Xpress Python API to invoke Knitro or Xpress SLP, specifically for choosing between local and global optimization methods? I am referring to the version of Knitro that is bundled with FICO Xpress. Previously, I attempted to switch the NLP solver using the following command, but it appears to no longer be effective:
`p.controls.nlpsolver = 1`

Has there been a change in how to properly configure this setting, or is there an alternative approach to select the solver and specify the solve method (local vs. global) within the current version of the FICO Xpress Python API?

Comment: What do you mean by "it appears to no longer be effective". Does it still run Xpress Global or does it run Xpress-SLP?

Comment: I mean it just errors when I pass on this argument. It doesn’t recognise it as valid